# OpenXML SDK - Combine multiple Excel Files

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have 2 files.
I have Test1.xlsx and Test2.xlsx that I need to combine it problematically.
What is the best way to do this? I am using C#, MVC 3.

I have seen mention of AltChunk  but have seen it used with Documents and SpreadSheets.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first..

Comment: Have not. Do not see any code that is ideal. I see code that works with docs but what I need is for Excel Files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need more information to answer this questions.

Do you want to write VBA code to combine them?  Do you want to just copy a tab from one of them and move it to the other?  Do they have similar column headers and would it make sense to use access to append them together?  It all depends on what you are trying to do.

If you just want to copy a tab from test1.xlsx to test2.xlsx then go to the correct tab in test1 and right click on the tab. then click move or copy. In the "to book" field select test2 (test2 will need to be open at the same time), and then select the create a copy box and click ok.

If you want to automate something that combines excel files together you could do it using VBA which is also another option.